# How to display a certain window on the output, using a video projector?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, projector

I want to connect my `MacBbook Pro` to a `video projector` without showing my desktop, menu bars, dock and anything else on the wall. Basically, I just want a **certain window** to be displayed.

How can I do it on my mac? Is there any app which provides this feature?

Comment: Is it OK to have some other things on the projector while you set it up?

Comment: yes it is fine.  @DAVincent